# Getting a strange nil in Rails with Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a strange nil problem with the following code.

The view (part of it):

```
<p>
  <%= label :maintenance, :name %>
  <%= text_field(:maintenance, :name, :size => 20) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= label :maintenance, :type %>
  <%= select :maintenance, :type, @m_types  %>
</p>
```

If I remove the text_field or move it below the select, I get a nil for the :maintenance in the select.

the controller method:

```
def new
  @log = Log.new
  @maintenance = Maintenance.new

  @m_types = Maintenance.types
  @cars = Car.all

  print @maintenance

  if not params[:car].nil?
@log.car = params[:car]
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @log }
  end
end
```

I'm assuming it must be some strange Ruby evaluation thing, but I have no idea what I'm looking for.  I searched around with Google, but not knowing what you're searching for makes that pretty hard.

TIA!

Thanks to all who helped out, but I refactored my models, changed my inheritance column and it works now.  I think the problem was that I was using :type as the inheritance column, so when I asked to set the :type in the select before I did the text_field it didn't know I was using a Maintenance object and it was looking for a regular object.  Any normal Ruby object uses the :type field for something else.  So it was looking for the :type set to a module, and not to a String as I was trying to do.

You can see my new [setup](http://aluink.pastebin.com/f3332bddb) that's working.  Hope someone can learn from this.

Comment: *What* exactly you get a `nil` for and *where* exactly does it happen?

Comment: As I said up there, the :maintenance in the select is nil.  But when I print @maintenance in the controller it's not nil.

Comment: It might be helpful to see your models and get a list of attributes/columns for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest that you use the form_for method to declare your forms.

In your case you can do (in your view):

```
form_for @maintenance do |f|
  f.label :name
  f.text_field :name
end
```

This will attach the form variables to your instance of @maintenance.

Check out this guide for more info on forms in Rails - [Dealing with Model Objects in Forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects)

Comment: i'm already using that, the problem is that i'm building two different types at once here, it's nested inside a form_for for a different type

Comment: I just used the fields_for construct, but that doesn't solve my problem, thanks though ;)

Comment: You could add virtual attributes to the Log class for :maintenance_type and :maintenance_name, then create the Maintenance record within the Log model.